# foundation show images only in mobile version

Tags: zurb-foundation

As I know large-12 class only show stuff on large screen. If I decrease the size like on mobile it won't show anything unless I assign another class small-12

Now I've this code and it's showing large-12 in mobile as well and small-12 on large screen as well.

> > ```
> >         <div class="row">
> > ```
>
> ```
>           <div class="large-12  columns">
>               <div class="panel">
>                                         <img src="design/images/nationalskills_logo.png" />
>                                         <img src="design/images/toyota_logo.png" style="float: right;"/>
>               </div>
>           </div>
>           <div class="small-6 columns">
>               <div class="panel">
>                                         <img style="width: 30%;" src="design/images/nationalskills_logo.png" />
>                                         <img style="width: 30%;"  src="design/images/toyota_logo.png" style="float: right;"/>
>               </div>
>           </div>
>                     </div>
> ```

Can anyone please help me out. 
I want to show larger-12 div on big screens and small-6 only on small screen not on big screen. What is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

12 class only show stuff on large screen. If I decrease the size like on mobile it won't show anything unless I assign another class small-12"
This assumption is totally wrong just see the doc http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html

For image resizing use interchange option.
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/interchange.html

You can use different size classes for coloumns in one single div which hides other class definitions based on size..

```
 <div class="row">
 <div class="small-6 large-6  columns">
 <div class="panel">
  <img data-interchange="[/path/to/default.jpg, (default)], [/path/to/bigger-image.jpg,   (large)]" />
 <img class="right" data-interchange="[/path/to/default.jpg, (default)],  [/path/to/bigger-image.jpg, (large)]" />                           
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```